# What can I do when an outside party hacks into my weblog and changes my display name?

Tags: database, security, user-meta, hacked

Last night I wrote a mildly controversial blog post about religion on my weblog, and this morning I woke up to find that my display name had been changed to the name of a fanatic religious leader. The name was actually added to the user_meta database; deleting that value reverted my display name back to my username.

How could this happen and what can I do to protect against it?

Comment: You're lucky that's all they did.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure to protect your file directories, don't make them writable by you only!

Red up:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Hardening_WordPress

And download:
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-security-scan/

Comment: Thanks, that helps... still, it's strange to think that someone was actually able to break into my site - I don't know what went wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Also ALWAYS use the lastest version of WordPress and use quility plugins.